# Fill a visio element with color using python

Tags: python, pywin32, visio

I’m using this code to draw myself a server in visio:

```
import win32com.client as w32
visio = w32.Dispatch("visio.Application")
visio.Visible = 1
doc = visio.Documents.Add("Detailed Network Diagram.vst")
page = doc.Pages.Item(1)
page.name = "My drawing"
stn2 = visio.Documents("Servers.vss")
server = stn2.Masters("Server")
serv = page.Drop(server, 0, 0)
for ssh in serv.shapes:
    ssh.Cells( 'Fillforegnd' ).FormulaForceU = 'RGB(255,0,0)'
```

And my problem is when I’m trying to fill the object with a color (instead of the regular server color) it doesn’t work.
Nothing really worked. I’m using python 3.8.

Comment: Did you try fill this server shape via user interface ?

Comment: I can also place the server via user interface. I need it to be fully automated.

Comment: You mean one of build-in Visio stencils? If `Yes` all masters there contain some sub-shapes into. And these sub-shapes dont inherent parent shape fill pattern! You must iterate all sub-shapes into and change fill pattern for each sub-shape...

Comment: How do I do that? Can you upload a snippet please?

Comment: I suspect a problem with the localisation of your software. I always run in the same problem. Try replacing the commas by semicolons in the RGB formula. Let us know your results.

Comment: @y4cine, we have long discussion in [secret room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246335/discussion-between-surrogate-and-eladtopaz)! **IMHO** problem with sub-shapes with THEMES support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code please

```
import win32com.client as w32
visio = w32.Dispatch("visio.Application")
visio.Visible = 1
doc = visio.activedocument
page = doc.pages(1)
page.name = "Mydrawing"
stn2 = visio.Documents(2)
server = stn2.Masters(2)
serv = page.Drop(server, 0, 0)
#iterate all sub-shapes into Serv-shape
for ssh in serv.shapes:
    ssh.Cells( 'Fillforegnd' ).FormulaForceU = 'RGB(255,255,0)'
```

---

If you dont need iterate all sub-shapes, you can change only same of them

```
#iterate 2nd, 3rd and 4rd sub-shapes into Serv-shape #     
for i in range (2,5):     
    ssh = serv.shapes(i)
    # if you need get solid color for sub-shapes uncomment next line    
    # ssh.Cells('FillPattern').FormulaForceU = '1'    
      ssh.Cells('Fillforegnd').FormulaU = 'RGB(255,255,0)'
```

Code in [my Jupyterlab notebook](https://github.com/Surrogate-TM/surrogate-tm.github.io/blob/master/jupyterlab/for_EladTopaz.ipynb) change only 3 sub-shapes, which i select and delete for demonstrate difference…
[image]

---

**PS** The user's problem was not in the code, but in the Visio sub-shapes, which did not want to inherit the color of the main shape. Because these sub-shapes had formulas that used functions like [THEMEGUARD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/themeguard-function) and [similar to it in their cells](https://shapesheet-kb.github.io/en/pages/categories/Themes.htm).
I modified the shape from the built-in set of elements and the problem was solved…

**PPS** Solved! To remove the dependency on those sub-shapes, you need to change their `Fillstyle` to `Normal`. Just add new line of code `ssh.FillStyle = 'Normal'`.
Look at code ↓

```
import win32com.client as w32
visio = w32.Dispatch("visio.Application")
visio.Visible = 1
# create document based on Detailed Network Diagram template (use full path)
doc = visio.Documents.Add ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\visio content\1033\dtlnet_m.vstx")
# use one of docked stencils 
stn2 = visio.Documents("PERIPH_M.vssx")
# define 'Server' master-shape
server = stn2.Masters("Server")
# define page
page = doc.Pages.Item(1)
# rename page
page.name = "My drawing"
# drop master-shape on page, define 'Server' instance
serv = page.Drop(server, 0, 0)
# iterate sub-shapes (side edges) 
for i in range (2,6):
    # define one od side edges from 'Server'
    ssh = serv.shapes(i) 
    # Change Fill Style to 'Normal'
    ssh.FillStyle = 'Normal'
    # fix FillForegnd cell for side edge
    ssh.Cells( 'Fillforegnd' ).FormulaForceU = 'Guard(Sheet.' + str(serv.id) +  '!FillForegnd)'
    # fix FillBkgnd cell for side edge
    ssh.Cells( 'FillBkgnd' ).FormulaForceU = 'Guard(Sheet.' + str(serv.id) +  '!FillBkgnd)'
    # instead formula 'Guard(x)' rewrite formula 'Guard(1)'    
    ssh.Cells( 'FillPattern' ).FormulaForceU = 'Guard(1)'

# fill main shape in 'Server' master-shape
serv.Cells("FillForegnd").FormulaForceU = '5'
```

Comment: I tried it but i got the error "pywintypes.com_error Cell is guarded”

Comment: I even tried to make a “try-expect” and change color only if it lets me, and no errors but no color change either…

Comment: For guarded cells you need use [FormulaForceU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.cell.formulaforceu) property! I update my previous answer

Comment: It still doesn’t work, look at my updated code, I run it and it placed the server, no errors but no color change too :/

Comment: Wow! I apply my code to.one master-shape from MS Visio build-in stencil with caption `Servers` but it have name not 'servers.vss', this stencil haven't contain master-shape `Server`. For this build-in stencil my code works fine! May be at your side you have 3rd-party stencil with some additional protection into? Can you share example document with this master-shape?

Comment: I can’t share an example document sadly, but I know I don’t work with 3rd-party stencil… and I tried your code too, it draw my a line instead of a server and it didn’t even paint it

Comment: I do not need a top secret example document (_I am not a russian spy_) ! I want to get a file containing one single shape Server, without  hostname or IP address.

Comment: I use line `stn2 = visio.Documents(2)`, because i have not stencil like at your side. I just open stencil which i have. This line drop master-shape from document which opened with my current document. [My 'Servers' stencil](https://i.imgur.com/PstV24e.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246335/discussion-between-surrogate-and-eladtopaz).